# Not picking up GetAsyncKeyState when my program is not in focus. not working while ingame

Tags: c++, winapi

My program picks up key states of <kbd>w</kbd> and <kbd>s</kbd> so that I can change a game's walk speed value. It only works when the game isn't actually picking up <kbd>w</kbd> key state in the game itself, because it changes the value back to its original value. But it does work if I only change the value and then the character would move by itself (without pressing <kbd>w</kbd>).

What I want to do is block the <kbd>w</kbd> key inputs into the game, which I did by a simple autohotkey script. But now I want my program to pick up the <kbd>w</kbd> keystrokes and then write to the game's memory and change its walking speed. Which I did correctly, but it only works when the game is out of focus, that's the only time my program picks up the key presses, not when the game is in focus.

I would also like an external (.exe) approach answer to this, since my program is fully external and I haven't played with internal yet.

The code below simply checks for an input from my keyboard and then writes to the game to change the walk speed only when picking up the <kbd>w</kbd> key. When <kbd>s</kbd> is pressed, it changes the walkspeed back to 0 to simulate stop walking.

```cpp
for (;;)
{
    if(GetAsyncKeyState('W') & 0x57)
    {
        WriteProcessMemory(handle, (LPVOID)FinalWalkSpeedPointer, &walkspeednewvalue, sizeof(walkspeednewvalue), NULL);
        ReadProcessMemory(handle, (LPVOID)FinalWalkSpeedPointer, &valueofwalkspeed, sizeof(valueofwalkspeed), NULL);
        std::cout << "Walkspeed is now: " << valueofwalkspeed << std::endl;
        system("cls");
    }
    if (GetAsyncKeyState('S') & 0x53)
    {
        WriteProcessMemory(handle, (LPVOID)FinalWalkSpeedPointer, &walkspeedstop, sizeof(walkspeedstop), NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you kindly divide your text into sentences, with a capital letter at the front and a period at the end? That would increase readability immensely. That said, as a new user, take the [tour] and read [ask]. Further, questions asking why code doesn't work must come with a [mcve] so everyone can reproduce the issue. Another advise, the "external" tag is pretty useless, but the "winapi" tag marking this as a Windows question would properly help categorize the question.

Comment: I know of only one way to mess with app's keyboard input: a [windows hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/hooks). Look into keyboard hook, and also low level keyboard hook. Problem is input focus. You can't have input focus in app1 and input processing in app2. They must happen in the same process.

Comment: @Anders thats hex code for W thats how i use its parameters and it works.

Comment: @Anders you noticed something bad with the code, but failed to explain why or offer a fix. For example "`GetAsyncKeyState` returns just a combination of bits 0x8000 and 0x0001, so doing a bitwise AND on it with 0x57 makes very little sense. What you should do instead is check for only `GetAsyncKeyState('W') & 1`".

Comment: @Dialecticus thanks ill check it out!

Comment: @Dialecticus except that it is bit 0x8000 you should be checking for and even then it is wrong because pulling this function is not the correct way to detect keystrokes.

Comment: @Dialecticus i checked out windows low level keyboard hook and that totally fixed my problem so thanks so much.

Comment: Happy to help. One final thing for you to would be to write your solution here as an answer, and accept your own answer (click on hollow check mark next to the answer to make it green), so that other people know the question is closed.

Comment: @Dialecticus I don't know why but im unable to see a checkbox anywher am i missing something

Comment: You have to provide an answer first. Like all other questions in Stack Overflow that have answers.

Comment: But [I see now](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) that you have to have 15 reputation points to be able to do that. You can gather that much just by reading all of the [tour introduction](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). EDIT: hm, no, reading the tour does not give you reputation. Well, leave this as it is for now, and once you get 15 rep get back to it to provide the answer.

Comment: @Dialecticus It was your suggestion initially, you could answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know too much about Windows hook, but this looks like a job for a global [low level keyboard hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644985(v=vs.85)).

In callback function by default you return the result of the call to `CallNextHookEx`, unless you want to block or "swallow" the key. In that case you do not call `CallNextHookEx` and just return a value different from zero (if I'm reading the manual correctly).